# docker command autocompletes in zsh but on executing throws not found error

Tags: docker, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

[image]

Check this for example, when I hit docker it autocompletes but when I press enter it throws command not found error. This works fine on Terminal but doesn't seem to be working on iTerm.

Comment: Is Terminal also using zsh or is it on bash? What does `which docker` return in Terminal?

Comment: Thanks. I had to uncomment the first line as I come from bash.

Comment: uncomment the first line of what?